# How would I capture the timestamp of when a link is clicked in an Email?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email

This may be a bit of a tricky one (for me at least, but you guys may be smarter). I need to capture the timestamp of exactly when a reader clicks a link in an email. However, this link is not a hyperlink to another webpage. It is a link formatted as a GET request with querystrings that will automatically submit a form.

Here is the tricky part....The form processing is not handled by PHP or .NET or any other server side language. It is a form engine that is hosted and managed by a cloud based marketing platform that captures and displays the form submission data (So i have no access to the code behind the scenes).

Now, if this wasn't an email I'd say it is simple enough to just use Javascript. However, javascript doesn't work so well with email, if at all (I'm just assuming there are some email clients out there that support javascript).

How would you go about capturing the timestamp for when the link is clicked without using any type of scripting? Is this even possible?

The best solution i could come up with was to have the link point to an intermediate page with javascript to capture timestamp and then redirect to the form submission. Only problem with that is that it will only capture timestamp of page load and not of the actual click activity.

Comment: If submission time isn't captured by the server already and it's a marketing platform then this sounds like you should probably contact the administrators of the server and enquire why it's missing/if it can be added

Comment: Obviously you're under no obligation to share, but I'm curious as to why you need millisecond resolution on an email click. Considering the inherent asynchronicity of email (delivery to server, retrieval by client, view by user, click on link, ...), it's hard to imagine the value in that degree of precision. In any case, I think the intermediate page approach is you best bet. You could record a timestamp on the intermediate server instead of using JavaScript in the intermediate page.

Comment: "Only problem with that is that it will only capture timestamp of page load and not of the actual click activity." What is the type of precision you need? Atomic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want "without any type of scripting". If no scripting is done, no functionality may be added or changed.

The best option is the very one you suggested: use an intermediary page that records the request time. Barring unusual circumstances (such as a downed server), the time between a link being clicked and the request reaching the server will be less than 1 second.

Do you really need a higher resolution or accuracy than ~1s? What additional gain is there from having results on the order of milliseconds or microseconds? I can't imagine a scenario in which you'd have tangible benefits from such a thing, though if you do have one I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought was to say that what you're trying to do can't be done without some scripting capability, but I suppose it truly depends on *what* you're trying to accomplish overall.

While there is ambiguity in what you're trying to accomplish from what you have written, I'm going to make an assumption: you're trying to record interaction with a particular email.

Depending on the desired resolution, this is very possible--in fact--something that most businesses have been doing for years.

To begin my explanation of the technique, consider this common functionality in most mail clients (web-based or otherwise):

```
Click here to display images below
```

The reason for this existing is that the images that are loaded into the message that you're reading often come from a *remote server* not hosted by the mail client. In the process of requesting that image, a great deal of information about yourself is given to that outside server via HTTP headers in your request ***including***, among other things, a ***timestamp*** for the request. Thus the above button is used to prevent that from happening without your consent.

That said, its also important to note how other mail client providers, most notably gmail, are approaching this now. The aforementioned technique is so common (used by advertisers and by other, more nefarious parties for the purpose of phishing, malware, etc) that Google has decided to start caching all mail images themselves. The result is that the email looks exactly the same, but all requests for images are instead directed at Google's cached versions.

Long story short, you can get a timestamp to note interaction with an email via image request, but such metric collection in general, regardless if its done in the manner I've outlined, is something mail clients try to prevent, at least at some level.

**EDIT** - To relate this back to what you mention in your question and your idea of having some intermediary page, you could skip having that page and instead you would point an image request towards a server *you* control